# Custom String padding with zeroes to 256-bit size key for AES/ECB/PKCS7Padding

Tags: android, ios, encryption, aes

## Question Description

I met a situation recently in which case I need to do a 256-AES cross platform encryption/decryption between iOS and Android with a pre-defined `String` key like this `PreDefinedKey`.

The AES implementation is done on iOS with [this code](http://pastie.org/426530), and all I need to do is to change the code on Android so that I can do "cross-platform" encryption/decryption.

*NOTE: I'm aware of that the AES code on iOS has a severe security/memory problem, but its currently not my concern :-)*

I was able to do the encryption/decryption on either Android and iOS individually. However it seemed the two AES implementations here have a trivial difference which prevented me to do the "cross-platform" encryption/decryption. For example, I put the Android encrypted String to iOS and it can't return a expected result (in this case, it returns null).

**Question:**

On both iOS and Android platform, I'm sure the algorithm is `AES/ECB/PKCS7Padding`, with `128-Rijndael` algorithm for AES implementation.

Both platform should use 256-bit size key. And with a deeper look inside of the iOS AES code I found that it actually uses `zeroes` to pad the key to 256-bit.

Here's the zero paddings related code snippet on iOS:

```
// 'key' should be 32 bytes for AES256, will be null-padded otherwise
    char keyPtr[kCCKeySizeAES256+1]; // room for terminator (unused)
    bzero(keyPtr, sizeof(keyPtr)); // fill with zeroes (for padding)
```

And here's the AES parameters in that code (it uses Rijndael-128 Algorithm, 256-bit key size, NULL for Initial Vectors):

```
CCCryptorStatus cryptStatus = CCCrypt(kCCEncrypt, kCCAlgorithmAES128, kCCOptionPKCS7Padding,
                                     keyPtr, kCCKeySizeAES256,
                                     NULL /* initialization vector (optional) */,
                                     [self bytes], dataLength, /* input */
                                     buffer, bufferSize, /* output */
                                     &numBytesEncrypted);
```

But on Android I don't know how to do the similar stuff, so could someone point out the right way for me?

---

## Code I'm Using

On **Android** platform, I use the code below to do AES implementation:

```
private static final String AES_SECRET = "PreDefinedKey";

/**
 * Method for AES encryption
 * @param raw
 * @param plain
 * @return
 * @throws Exception
 */
private static byte[] encrypt(byte[] raw, byte[] plain) throws Exception {
    SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(raw, "AES/ECB/PKCS7Padding");
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS7Padding");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec);
    byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(plain);
    return encrypted;
}



/**
 * AES decryption
 * @param encryptMsg
 * @return
 * @throws Exception
 */
public static String AESDecrypt(String encryptMsg)
        throws Exception {          
    byte[] rawKey = getRawKey(AES_SECRET.getBytes());
    //byte[] enc = toByte(encryptMsg);
    byte[] enc = Base64.decode(encryptMsg, 0);
    byte[] result = decrypt(rawKey, enc);
    return new String(result);

}

/**
 * Method for AES decryption
 * @param raw
 * @param encrypted
 * @return
 * @throws Exception
 */
private static byte[] decrypt(byte[] raw, byte[] encrypted) throws Exception {
    SecretKeySpec keySpec = new SecretKeySpec(raw, "AES/ECB/PKCS7Padding");
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS7Padding");
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, keySpec);
    byte[] decrypted = cipher.doFinal(encrypted);
    return decrypted;

}

public static byte[] getRawKey(byte[] seed) throws Exception {

    KeyGenerator kgen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
    SecureRandom sr = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");
    sr.setSeed(seed);
    //Init for 256bit AES key
    kgen.init(256);
    SecretKey secret = kgen.generateKey();
    //Get secret raw key
    byte[] raw = secret.getEncoded();

    return seed;

}
```

In the method of `getRawKey()`, it uses `SHA1PRNG` to generate random paddings to make the AES key to 256-bit size which is different from the iOS implementation (it uses zeroes to pad the key to 256-bit).

So, how do I change this method so that I can use my pre-defined string key which is padded with zeroes to 256-bit?

Please let me know if you require more info. Thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find whoever came up with this zero-padded scheme and have them fired. Then have the app reviewed.

As for your question, simply create a byte array of length 32 and copy the key bytes a the beginning, the use it to initialize `SecretKeySpec`. The `KeyGenerator` will generate a random key, and the whole 'fixed seed' idea is flawed and doesn't work on latest Android version. Here's some code:

```
// zeros by default
byte[] rawKey = new byte[32];
// if you don't specify the encoding you might get weird results
byte[] keyBytes = AES_SECRET.getBytes("ASCII");
System.arraycopy(keyBytes, 0, rawKey, 0, keyBytes.length);
SecretKey key = new SecretKeySpec(rawKey, "AES");
Cipher cipher = ...
// rest of your decryption code
```

Comment: cool, I just pop-in and tried ur approach, it WORKS! One more question: may I know why(or how) is the 'fixed size' stuff not work on latest Android?

Comment: I meant 'fixed seed'. Here: http://android-developers.blogspot.jp/2013/02/using-cryptography-to-store-credentials.html